# Selecting from A list in Excel from the same List

Tags: excel

I have a list of Names in Excel like this:

```
A         B
A Name
B Name
C Name
D Name
```

Column A will have all the names, and the user will select in Column B all the available names in Column A. That I know how to do, but the problem is, Is it possible to remove the Name in the Dropdown when it is already selected

For example I have already selected

```
A         B
A Name    C Name
B Name
C Name    A Name
D Name
```

Then the Dropdown list will only have

```
B Name
D Name
```

Then the selected match will flow down to its match in the list like I selected C for A, then automatically C will be filled with A

Is this possible in Excel, any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one Combo, following the scheme:

[image]

Add the code:

```
D3 -> =IFERROR(INDEX(ResA;SMALL(IF(ResA<>"";ROW(ResA)-MIN(ROW(ResA))+1);ROW(K1)));"")
D9 -> =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;$B$2:$B$5;1;FALSE);1)=1;A2;"")
```

and autocomplete. The D3 section is an array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter when insert).
Insert the Name Range:

```
D2:D6 -> ListA
D9:D12 -> ResA
```

In the Combo, ListFillRange it's equal to ListA.
The following, return in the combo only the value not used in the col B (Range B2:B5).
If you have 4 or more, it's a little bit more complicated, but the base it's the same. Use dedicated list to reduce the value to insert in the combo. After you can hide these columns.